# How do i create an email button that will submit to web form php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I am trying to make a javascript function in html that will accept email addresses and then submit them to a web form. How do I do this? this is what I have so far:

```
<html>
<form name="form" method="post" action="form-action.php">
<label>
Email:
</label>
<input type="email" name="email"
id="email" size="25" />

<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SubmitEmail()" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SubmitEmail() {

                if (!ValidateForm()) {

                    return false;

                }


                document.getElementById("form").submit();
function ValidateForm() {
if (document.getElementById('email').value.length === 0) {

alert("Email is Required");

return false;

}

document.getElementById('EmailRslt').value = document.getElementById('email').value;

return true;

}

</script> 
<td>Your Email is:
</td>
<td id="EmailRslt"></td>
</html>
```

Comment: And the issue? also move the validateForm function outside the other function

Comment: `.value` is only valid for input elements, not for `<td>`. Use `.innerHTML` to set the contents of a TD. But I'm not sure what this has to do with your question, setting a TD doesn't submit a web form.

Comment: `document.getElementById("form").submit();` where is form with an id of 'form'?

Answer (score 0):

in your form-action.php fire insert query which will submit 
  data in your database table.

Answer (score 0):

replace `if (document.getElementById('email').value.length === 0)` this line with

```
if (document.getElementById('email').value.length == 0)
```

Comment: I don't think that's gonna change anything, and "===" is more preferable than "=="